# Как создать триггер google sheet на изменение таблицы скриптом?

Tags: google-apps-script

Необходимо создать триггер в таблице 1, при изменении таблицы 1 триггер срабатывает и отправляет get запрос в другую таблицу 2. В таблице 2 проверяет на занят ли лист пользователем и если нет, то обновляет данные на лист 1 с таблицы 1 в лист 1 таблицы 2.

я сделал триггер по изменению.Кстати, не понял чем отличается события **при изменении и при редактировании**. Скриншот ниже:

[image: Тип события]

Я создал функцию OnEdit() и задал ей тригер. Почему-то штатная onEdit() не работает. 
Код

```
function OnEdit() {    
//  do something...
}
```

Если заходишь в таблицу, что-то редактируешь, работает. Но если из другой таблицы скрипт вносит строки или изменения, то OnEdit() не запускается. То есть OnEdit() не реагирует на изменения, внесенные скриптами.

Прошу помочь, как сделать, чтобы реагировал на изменения, внесенные скриптами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, не `OnEdit`, а `onEdit` ?

`onEdit` - зарезервированная команда листинга скрипта, которая указывает на исполнение simple trigger при срабатывании события `EDIT`.

- Перечисления событий в документации
  [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- Официальный гайд по триггерам [Triggers and Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Без понимания этих вещей не получится создавать достойные приложения. Все советы в интернетах основаны на пустом "скопировал-вставил". Так это не работает. А работает это вот так:

Событие `EDIT` вызывает триггер, когда

> ... a user changes a value in a spreadsheet

что означает, в переводе "пользователь". Ни другой скрипт, ни внешнее приложение, ни вызов REST API не инициируюут этого события.

Логично предположить, что `onEdit` - функция привязанная к проекту-контейнеру определенной Таблицы. Т.к. в отдельном контейнере нет Таблицы, которую можно вызывать.

Ознакомиться с ограничениями на simple triggers, см. [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions). Другими словами, нельзя заменить `onEdit` на `installable` триггер, потому что там много ограничений.

Comment: Возможно, вам стоит пересмотреть работу самого приложения и выбрать другой путь.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю создать триггер по времени 1 минута.

в таблице2 "отображенные данные" проверяются в каждой строке и начинаются изменения, если в определённом столбце есть какое-то ЗНАЧЕНИЕ, являющееся триггером для вашего триггера по времени. \

также в скрипте пропишите, чтобы это ЗНАЧЕНИЕ менялось на "обработано" или что-то вроде того. для того, чтобы скрипт больше не касался этой строки.

P.S: Сумбурно, но, надеюсь, задумка ясна